# Asp.net multilanguage website validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I did multilanguage website.All work great.I save my translates in .resx files. But validation message show only in one languge.
My code is

```
public class CultureAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string cultureName = null;
        // Получаем куки из контекста, которые могут содержать установленную культуру
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["lang"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
            cultureName = "ru";

        // Список культур
        List<string> cultures = new List<string>() { "ru", "en" };
        if (!cultures.Contains(cultureName))
        {
            cultureName = "ru";
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //не реализован
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide more, like your validation message show, your validation control

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `.resx` files to provide validation messages on your model:

```
[Required(
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), 
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "UsernameIsRequiredMessage")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```